# React native on linux "The SDK directory '/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk' does not exist."

Tags: android, linux, reactjs, android-studio, react-native

I was installing the react native following the steps of facebook page, and when I run the command react-native run-android happened this error. i've already set the adnroid SDK in the android studio, but i think doesn't work, i don't what is happening, any help i aprecciate. my OS is linux manjaro, i'm beginner any error forgive me.

```
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> The SDK directory '/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> The SDK directory '/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:639:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:657:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (/home/bruno/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:75:39)
    at buildAndRun (/home/bruno/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:137:41)
    at then.result (/home/bruno/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:103:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)
```

---

[.bash_profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUAdZ.png)

[local.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uAam.png)

[android list target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0Ng1.png)

Comment: and where is your Android SDK installed to?

Comment: in the android studio say's android SDK home path is in /home/bruno/Android/Sdk

Comment: change your local.properties to match your path above

Comment: see the pic below of the local.properties, and doesn't work with the path in android studio